# Write access violation c++ when i try to save from one variable to another

Tags: c++

```
struct Array {
    int length = 5;
    int *first_cell;

    void create() {
        int *arr = new int[length * sizeof(int)];
        *first_cell = *arr;
    }
    void random_fill() {
        int k;
        srand(5);
        for (k = 0; k < length; k++) {
            first_cell[k] = rand() % 10;
            printf("| %d", first_cell[k]);
        }
    }
};
```

This line gives me error:

```
 *first_cell = *arr;
```

Error:

*Exception thrown: write access violation.
this->first_cell was 0xCCCCCCCC.*

Comment: `first_cell = arr;`

Comment: Ok, now which line of the shown code initializes `first_cell`, so when this line dereferences it, it's a valid pointer? And what exactly is the point of: 1) allocating a new array, and then 2) immediately take the completely uninitialize value from the array and putting it at a location referenced by another pointer? What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: `int *arr = new int[length * sizeof(int)];` is wrong. In `c++` you just specify the number of elements in the array. It's not like malloc where you specify the # of bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to save the pointer to *arr* in *first_cell*.

So write it like:

```
first_cell = arr
```